# T-SQL query from .NET starts running extremely slowly after a while, even when program is restarted

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5

I have a .NET 4.5 program that basically runs a loop in which the same stored procedure is executed many times, using the same `SqlConnection`. If a command timeout occurs, it is incremented and the query is re-run (this is for testing purposes, in the real application the input parameters to the SP would be modified).

The stored procedure in question can be found below. Basically it is a mix of `SELECT/DELETE/UPDATE` statements. It starts with `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and contains no `BEGIN TRAN` or `ROLLBACK TRAN` statements.

After running this program for a while, it seems that the queries are starting to run really slow. Restarting the program does not help, the queries are still running slow. It appears that this slowdown happens after a command timeout has occurred. But running the same query in sql server management studio shows no slowdown.

I did some troubleshooting, and copied the SQL and pasted it in a query window in SQL Server Management Studio and tried running it from there (After a `CHECKPOINT; DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`, and within a `BEGIN TRAN/ROLLBACK TRAN`). It ran in about 4 seconds. Consecutive runs takes about 0.5 seconds.

Then I did the same from a new .NET console application, and the query was running extremely slow, about 48 seconds (this is the duration shown by the SQL Server as well, so it is really executing the query that takes this amount of time). Consecutive runs takes about 17 seconds.

Simply running an `ALTER` command to update the SP (without changing it) actually "solves" the problem, and the queries run fast everywhere again, until they start running slow again.

I have also tried using `SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()`, but this does not appear to help.

What on earth can cause this behavior? I can't think of any reason why SQL Server would start behaving this way.  Why would a query suddenly start running faster if an SP is updated? (And why would it slow down in the first place, but only from connections from .NET)

**Edit:** 
I have now also tried to `KILL` all SPIDs possible from `sys.sysprocesses` that were using the database in question. There are a number of system processes that cannot be killed, but this did not resolve the problem.  `sys.dm_tran_locks` shows no locks being held (Except a single shared database lock).

**Edit 2:**
Bringing the database offline, and then back online also seems to remedy the problem. (Until it occurs again). But what can cause this problem?

Here is the method used for provoking the problem:

```
 static void BasicTest()
  {

     const string connectionString = "Server=.;Initial Catalog=Filler;Integrated Security=SSPI";

     const string sql = @"declare @p3 bigint
      set @p3=NULL
      declare @p4 bigint
      set @p4=NULL
      declare @p5 bigint
      set @p5=NULL
      declare @p6 bigint
      set @p6=NULL
      declare @p7 bigint
      set @p7=NULL
      declare @p8 bit
      set @p8=NULL
      exec dbo.spRunTrackingCleanupBatch @BatchSize=3000,@SessionId=1,@NonDeletableEntityCount=@p3 output,@DeletedNodeCount=@p4 output,@DeletedEventCount=@p5 output,@DeletedJobCount=@p6 output,@DeletedLogEntryCount=@p7 output,@IsComplete=@p8 output
      select @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8";

     int commandTimeout = 3;

     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
        conn.Open();
        bool isComplete = false;
        while (!isComplete)
        {
           try
           {
              using (SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
              {
                 using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
                 {
                    command.Transaction = tran;
                    command.CommandText = sql;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;

                    Console.WriteLine("Running query...");
                    Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                       reader.Read();
                       isComplete = reader.GetBoolean(5);
                    }
                    w.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}", w.Elapsed);
                    if (w.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40))
                       throw new Exception("Too slow!!!");                        
                 }

                 tran.Commit();
              }
           }
           catch (SqlException sex)
           {
              if (sex.IsTimeout())
              {
                 Console.WriteLine("TIMEOUT!!!");
                 commandTimeout += 5;
                 conn.Close();
                 conn.Open();
              }
              else
              {
                 throw;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

The stored procedure `spRunTrackingCleanupBatch`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRunTrackingCleanupBatch]
(
   @SessionId int,            
   @BatchSize int,            
   @IsComplete bit OUTPUT,
   @NonDeletableEntityCount bigint OUTPUT,
   @DeletedNodeCount bigint OUTPUT,
   @DeletedEventCount bigint OUTPUT,
   @DeletedJobCount bigint OUTPUT,
   @DeletedLogEntryCount bigint OUTPUT
)
AS 
BEGIN
   SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

   SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY -8;

   IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR(N'spRetrieveEventMatchesForProcessing must be executed in a transaction.', 18, 1)        
      RETURN
   END

   SET @NonDeletableEntityCount=0;
   SET @DeletedNodeCount=0
   SET @DeletedEventCount=0
   SET @DeletedJobCount=0
   SET @DeletedLogEntryCount=0

   DECLARE @DateUpperBound datetime2 
   SELECT @DateUpperBound=fldDateUpperBound FROM tblTrackingCleanupSessions WHERE fldSessionId=@SessionId

   IF @DateUpperBound IS NULL
      RAISERROR(N'The tracking cleanup session with Id %d does not exist.', 18, 1, @SessionId)

   DECLARE @RootEntityKeys tvpTrackingEntityKeyList

   DELETE TC 
      OUTPUT DELETED.fldEntityId, DELETED.fldEntityTypeId INTO @RootEntityKeys
      FROM tblTrackingCleanupCandidates TC
      INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) fldEntityId, fldEntityTypeId FROM tblTrackingCleanupCandidates WHERE fldSessionId=@SessionId 
         ORDER BY fldCreationTime DESC
         ) Q 
         ON Q.fldEntityId=TC.fldEntityId AND Q.fldEntityTypeId=TC.fldEntityTypeId AND TC.fldSessionId=@SessionId

   DECLARE @CandidateEntityKeys TABLE
   (
      fldIsCleanupPrevented bit,
      fldTimestamp datetime2,
      fldEntityTypeId tinyint,
      fldEntityId int,
      PRIMARY KEY (fldEntityTypeId, fldEntityId)
   )

   ; WITH
   Base AS
   (
      SELECT Roots.fldEntityTypeId AS fldRootEntityTypeId, Roots.fldId AS fldRootId, C.* FROM @RootEntityKeys Roots
         CROSS APPLY dbo.ft_GetTrackingCleanupTree(Roots.fldId, Roots.fldEntityTypeId) C
   ),
   Agg AS
   (
      SELECT fldRootId, SUM(fldIsTransientState) AS fldIsCleanupPrevented, MAX(fldTimestamp) AS fldMaxTimestamp FROM Base
         GROUP BY fldRootId
   )
   INSERT INTO @CandidateEntityKeys (fldIsCleanupPrevented, fldTimestamp, fldEntityTypeId, fldEntityId)
      SELECT DISTINCT Agg.fldIsCleanupPrevented, MAX(Agg.fldMaxTimestamp), fldEntityTypeId, fldId FROM Base 
         INNER JOIN Agg ON Base.fldRootId=Agg.fldRootId   
         GROUP BY Agg.fldIsCleanupPrevented, fldEntityTypeId, fldId               
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32677) 

   SELECT @NonDeletableEntityCount=@@ROWCOUNT

   DECLARE @DeletableKeys tvpTrackingEntityKeyList

   INSERT INTO @DeletableKeys (fldEntityTypeId, fldId)
      SELECT fldEntityTypeId, fldEntityId FROM @CandidateEntityKeys 
      WHERE fldIsCleanupPrevented=0 AND fldTimestamp <= @DateUpperBound

   SELECT @NonDeletableEntityCount=@NonDeletableEntityCount-@@ROWCOUNT

   DELETE TC 
      FROM tblTrackingCleanupCandidates TC
      INNER JOIN (
         SELECT CC.fldEntityTypeId, CC.fldEntityId FROM @CandidateEntityKeys CEK
            OUTER APPLY dbo.fn_GetTrackingEntityParentList(fldEntityTypeId, fldEntityId) CC
            WHERE CEK.fldIsCleanupPrevented<>0 OR CEK.fldTimestamp > @DateUpperBound
      ) Q ON Q.fldEntityId=TC.fldEntityId AND Q.fldEntityTypeId=TC.fldEntityTypeId
      WHERE TC.fldSessionId=@SessionId

   EXEC dbo.spDeleteTrackingEntities @DeletableKeys,@DeletedNodeCount OUTPUT, @DeletedJobCount OUTPUT, @DeletedLogEntryCount OUTPUT, @DeletedEventCount OUTPUT

   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblTrackingCleanupCandidates WHERE fldSessionId=@SessionId)
      SET @IsComplete = 0
   ELSE
      SET @IsComplete = 1

END
```

The stored procedure `spDeleteTrackingEntities`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDeleteTrackingEntities]
   @EntityKeys AS tvpTrackingEntityKeyList READONLY,
   @DeletedNodeCount bigint OUTPUT,
   @DeletedJobCount bigint OUTPUT,
   @DeletedLogEntryCount bigint OUTPUT,
   @DeletedEventCount bigint OUTPUT  
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
   -- Job = 59, Event = 19, Node=18, Log=20
   SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;

   IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR(N'spRetrieveEventMatchesForProcessing must be executed in a transaction.', 18, 1)
      RETURN
   END

   CREATE TABLE #DeletedEntityKeys
   (
      fldEntityTypeId tinyint,
      fldId bigint,
      CONSTRAINT PK_DeletedEntityKeys PRIMARY KEY (fldEntityTypeId, fldId)
   )

   CREATE TABLE #DeletedArgumentRefs 
   (
      fldArgumentId bigint NOT NULL
   )

   SET @DeletedEventCount=0
   SET @DeletedJobCount=0
   SET @DeletedLogEntryCount=0
   SET @DeletedNodeCount=0

   DELETE TR FROM tblTrackingReferences TR
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON (TR.fldRefereeId=EK.fldId AND TR.fldRefereeType=EK.fldEntityTypeId) 

   DELETE TR FROM tblTrackingReferences TR
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON (TR.fldReferrerId=EK.fldId AND TR.fldRefereeId=EK.fldEntityTypeId)

   DELETE L 
      OUTPUT 20, DELETED.fldLogId INTO #DeletedEntityKeys
      FROM dbo.tblLog L
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=20 AND EK.fldId=L.fldLogId

   SELECT @DeletedLogEntryCount=@@ROWCOUNT

   DELETE NR
      FROM tblNodeRelation NR
      INNER JOIN tblNode N ON (NR.fldNodeId=N.fldNodeId OR NR.fldRelNodeId=N.fldNodeId)
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=18 AND (EK.fldId=NR.fldNodeId OR EK.fldId=NR.fldRelNodeId)
      WHERE N.fldRetain=0

   DELETE N 
      OUTPUT 18, DELETED.fldNodeId INTO #DeletedEntityKeys
      FROM dbo.tblNode N
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=18 AND EK.fldId=N.fldNodeId
      WHERE N.fldRetain=0

   SELECT @DeletedNodeCount=@@ROWCOUNT

   DELETE TR FROM dbo.tblTrackingReferences TR 
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblLog L ON (TR.fldRefereeId=L.fldLogId AND TR.fldRefereeType=20) 
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblJobs J ON J.fldJobId=L.fldJobId
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=J.fldJobId

   DELETE TR FROM dbo.tblTrackingReferences TR 
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblLog L ON (TR.fldReferrerId=L.fldLogId AND TR.fldReferrerType=20)         
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblJobs J ON J.fldJobId=L.fldJobId
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=J.fldJobId

   DELETE L 
      OUTPUT 20, DELETED.fldLogId INTO #DeletedEntityKeys
      FROM dbo.tblLog L
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblJobs J ON J.fldJobId=L.fldJobId
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=J.fldJobId

   SELECT @DeletedLogEntryCount=@DeletedLogEntryCount+@@ROWCOUNT

   UPDATE N SET N.fldJobId=NULL FROM dbo.tblNode N
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblJobs J ON J.fldJobId=N.fldJobId
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=J.fldJobId
      WHERE N.fldRetain=1

   DELETE N 
      FROM tblNodeRelation NR
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblNode N ON N.fldNodeId=NR.fldNodeId OR N.fldNodeId=NR.fldRelNodeId
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=N.fldJobId
      WHERE N.fldRetain=0

   DELETE N 
      OUTPUT 18, DELETED.fldNodeId INTO #DeletedEntityKeys
      FROM dbo.tblNode N 
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblJobs J ON J.fldJobId=N.fldJobId
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=J.fldJobId

   SELECT @DeletedNodeCount=@DeletedNodeCount+@@ROWCOUNT

   UPDATE J SET fldParentJobId=NULL FROM dbo.tblJobs J
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=J.fldJobId

   UPDATE E SET E.fldJobId=NULL FROM dbo.tblEvents E
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=19 AND EK.fldId=E.fldEventId

   DELETE JA 
      OUTPUT DELETED.fldArgumentId INTO #DeletedArgumentRefs
      FROM dbo.tblJobArguments JA
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=JA.fldJobId

   DELETE JOA FROM dbo.tblJobOutArguments JOA
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=JOA.fldJobId

   UPDATE EH SET EH.fldJobId=NULL FROM tblEventHistory EH         
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=EH.fldJobId

   UPDATE JH SET JH.fldCallerJobId=NULL FROM tblJobHistory JH 
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=JH.fldCallerJobId

   UPDATE JH SET JH.fldRelatedJobId=NULL FROM tblJobHistory JH 
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=JH.fldRelatedJobId

   DELETE J 
      OUTPUT 59, DELETED.fldJobId INTO #DeletedEntityKeys         
      FROM dbo.tblJobs J
         INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=59 AND EK.fldId=J.fldJobId

   SELECT @DeletedJobCount=@DeletedJobCount+@@ROWCOUNT

   DELETE EA 
      OUTPUT DELETED.fldArgumentId INTO #DeletedArgumentRefs
      FROM dbo.tblEventArguments EA         
      INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=19 AND EK.fldId=EA.fldEventId

   DELETE E 
      OUTPUT 19, DELETED.fldEventId INTO #DeletedEntityKeys         
      FROM dbo.tblEvents E
         INNER JOIN @EntityKeys EK ON EK.fldEntityTypeId=19 AND EK.fldId=E.fldEventId

   SELECT @DeletedEventCount=@DeletedEventCount+@@ROWCOUNT

   DELETE FROM A 
      FROM dbo.tblArguments A   
      INNER JOIN #DeletedArgumentRefs DA ON DA.fldArgumentId=A.fldArgumentId      
      WHERE A.fldArgumentId NOT IN (SELECT fldArgumentId FROM tblJobArguments)
      AND   A.fldArgumentId NOT IN (SELECT fldArgumentId FROM tblEventArguments)

   DELETE TCC FROM dbo.tblTrackingCleanupCandidates TCC
      INNER JOIN #DeletedEntityKeys DK ON DK.fldEntityTypeId=TCC.fldEntityTypeId AND Dk.fldId=TCC.fldEntityId

   MERGE tblDeletedNodeIds AS TARGET
      USING (SELECT fldId FROM #DeletedEntityKeys WHERE fldEntityTypeId=18) AS SOURCE ON TARGET.fldNodeId=SOURCE.fldId
      WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
         INSERT (fldNodeId) VALUES (SOURCE.fldId);

   DROP TABLE #DeletedEntityKeys
   DROP TABLE #DeletedArgumentRefs
END
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your query + connection to database? When you use the Window Task Manager are the Memory/CPU correct?

Comment: The query is just executing an SP. The SP is very lengthy though, but just does a bunch of SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE statements. When looking at the Task manager, the disk usage of MSSQL-server is at 100% for the duration of the query, whether it is running slow or fast. Not sure what you mean with the "connection" to the database, I'm using SqlConection/SqlTransaction/SqlCommand within using-statements in my test program. The real program has a bit more complicated of a setup, but basically boils down to the same thing.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you correctly dispose your connection/objects to MySQL server. So the problem seems to be inside MySQL. How long your stored procedure take if you manually run it inside MySQL? Is your stored procedure ran by a loop or other users?

Comment: I'm not using MySql but Microsoft SQL Server 2012. If I run the query manually from within Management Studio it takes about 4 seconds the first run and 0.5 seconds on consecutive runs, vs. 48 seconds/7 seconds from the test program. (Until I restart the server or update the stored procedure with some dummy code or whatever) after which the test program runs with the same times.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Why do you call `tran.Rollback();`? Try to add `conn.Close();`. Don't you think the problem could be inside `spRunTrackingCleanupBatch`?

Comment: I rollback in my test here just so I can use the same data for each test run. (The SP modifies the database). The actual code normally commits the transaction of course. The problem might be in the SP, but I can't see what it would be, since it works fine most of the time, up until something happens that causes it to always run slow when called from .NET.

Comment: Adding `conn.Close()` makes no difference (luckily enough, this should be handled by the `Dispose` call.)

Comment: Let us see what is in spRunTrackingCleanupBatch

Comment: @Kamran: Okay, added the full content of the stored procedures involved.

Comment: Determine which statement is taking longer and longer using SQL Profiler.

Comment: you have to narrow down the problamatic query in it. Also the performance will also depends on the indexes you have on the tables.

Comment: The problem is not the basic performance of the query. The problem is that all of a sudden the performance is degraded tremendously when running via a .NET application. Running the same query (with the same data) from within SQL server studio has much better performance when this has happened. If I for example restart the SQL server the performance is once again the same (good) one in both the .NET app and SQL-server.

Comment: @usr This vaires depending on the data being processed. Sometimes the first recursive CTE is what's taking the longest, and other times it's DELETE-statements. But the issue is that they take longer in the .NET app than in SQL-server mgmt studio, and nothing I do short of restarting the server/taking db offline/online etc will restore the performance to the .NET app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a bit strange, but it seems that running the SP with `WITH RECOMPILE` fixes the problem somehow.  At first I tried with `SET ARITHABORT ON` which made the query faster, but after running it a bunch of times it was suddenly faster if I changed it to `SET ARITHABORT OFF`.

Recompiling the stored procedure obviously changes the execution plans, and that seems to speed up things. So I guess I will have to add the `WITH RECOMPILE` to the execution of the stored procedure every now and then in my loop...

The documentation says that 
*SQL Server automatically recompiles stored procedures and triggers when it is advantageous to do this.* Apparently this is not always true though.